# Find interface for route to specific host

Tags: linux, networking, routing

On a multihomed Linux machine, how can I find out what network interface will be used to send a packet to a specific host? I need to do this programmatically and I'd rather not parse and interpret the routing table myself.

Comment: That's what routing table is for. I don't imagine it otherwise.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `ip route` for this. For instance:

```
ip route show to match 198.252.206.16
```

Answer (score 36):

Shorter option:

```
ip route get 172.29.42.94
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as Michael Hampton suggests, use `ip route`. If you only want the interface, use this

```
ip -o route get $ip | perl -nle 'if ( /dev\s+(\S+)/ ) {print $1}'
```

For example:

```
# ip=8.8.8.8
# iface=$( ip -o route get $ip | perl -nle 'if ( /dev\s+(\S+)/ ) {print $1}' )
# echo $iface
eth1
```